# How to update funtiction in PHP to get working SELECT list to work as a MultiSelect list

Tags: php, select

The below code is used in a PHP page to create a selections list and it works for us. But now we would need to get the selection list to be multiselect.

How the code would need to be updated so that it would work as multiselect?

```
function createSelectionList($controlName, $table, $valueColumn, $descriptionColumn, $mandatory=false) {
  global $conn, $tokens_Select;

  $cssClass = 'trafficFormItem';
  if($mandatory) {
    $cssClass .= 'm';
  }

  $selectListSql = "SELECT ".$valueColumn.", ".$descriptionColumn." FROM ".$table." ORDER BY ".$descriptionColumn;
  $selectListRs = &$conn->Execute($selectListSql);

  if (!$selectListRs) {
    echo('<span style="color: #cc0000;>An error occured: '.$conn->ErrorMsg().'</span>');
  }else {
    echo('<select name="'.$controlName.'" id="'.$controlName.'" class="'.$cssClass.'">');
    echo('<option value="" selected>('.$tokens_Select.'...)&nbsp;</option>');
    while (!$selectListRs->EOF){
      echo('<option value="'.$selectListRs->fields[0].'">'.$selectListRs->fields[1].'</option>');
      $selectListRs->MoveNext();
    }
    echo('</select>');
  }                                 
}
```

Comment: the native `<select multiple>` is not the prettiest or user-friendliest. i suggest the great [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) library.

Answer (score 1):

`<select multiple>` will let you select multiple values in a select box.

Hold down the Ctrl (windows) / Command (Mac) button to select multiple options.

In you code change the add `multiple` to the following line

```
echo('<select multiple name="'.$controlName.'" id="'.$controlName.'"
       class="'.$cssClass.'">');
```

Comment: It does not allow you to select multiple options. That is the problem. we need to change the code so that the  type of the list is multiselect.

Comment: Where should the <select multiple> be added in the code?

Comment: Thanks nauphal. I got the PHP to work now but I am unable to store more than 1 selection. So the acutal interface works but only the item that is selected last is stored. How to update so that it would store all the selected items?